# Why is regex_match a function and not a method of class regex?

Tags: regex, c++11

The `regex` class only specifies the search pattern, the algorithms (search and replace are the same) are functions that require a `regex` object as parameter.

The [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-regex) is not yet done on regular expressions.

So I'm asking here: what could be the reasoning in an object oriented language/library to separate the algorithms from the object?

Comment: Highly related reading: [How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STL is not exactly object oriented. Even though it *uses* classes and objects, it is based on the principles of [Generic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming).

For the reasons to separate the objects from the algorithms you can read the excellent book of Alexander Stepanov: [From Mathematics to Generic Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321942043)